# How do I make my document automatically delete? With Mongoose in javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose
this is my schema:

```js
const ShortUrlModel = mongoose.model(
  'ShortUrl',
  new mongoose.Schema({
    original_url: String,
    hash: String,
    expires_at: { type: Date, expires: 5000 },
  }),
);
```

I put expires in 5 secound for test, but it does not work

i wanna expire in 10 days.

when posting to my server to add a url

```js
fastify.post('/new', async (request, reply) => {
  let original_url = request.body.url;
  let hash = request.body.hash;
  const today = new Date();
  const expires_at = new Date();
  expires_at.setDate(today.getDate() + 10);

  let short = await ShortUrlModel.findOne({ hash });

  if (short) {
    ...
  } else {
    const newShortener = new ShortUrlModel({
      original_url,
      hash,
      expires_at,
    });

    let saveUrl = await newShortener.save();

    console.log(saveUrl);
    reply.send({
      ...
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is `expireAfterSeconds`

```
const ShortUrlModel = mongoose.model(
  'ShortUrl',
  new mongoose.Schema({
    original_url: String,
    hash: String,
  }, {
    expireAfterSeconds: 5000
  }),
);
```

Also note if you change the number of seconds, **you need to delete the index and recreate the index**. Change does not happen just because you change the seconds in your schema declaration.

More on changing of expire [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/#change-the-expireafterseconds-value-for-a-ttl-index)

Note 2: Expiration of documents in Mongodb does not happen instantly (e.g. exactly 5 seconds). This is stated in the mongodb [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/#delete-operations).

> The TTL index does not guarantee that expired data will be deleted immediately upon expiration. There may be a delay between the time that a document expires and the time that MongoDB removes the document from the database.

Comment: You could manually adjust the expire time on the index without dropping it if you'd prefer: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/collMod/#mongodb-collflag-index